# Is it okay to have entity class that doesn't use database?

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, servlets

I have a program that uses annotations and another one that is using fist one as dependency. I was able to do that thanks to `persistance.xml`. But I added validator class to first one (desktop app) because second one is web app and have some new possibilities like attaching files so I created validator class for it. At this moment I created dao and model layer for it in second program sources but I want to add it to first one instead.

If I don't add tag `@Entity` to this class then I can;t add it to `persistence.xml` so my second program can't find that source.

Is it okay to add `@Entity` when Validator does not and will not use database and there is no table for it?

I know it works because I tested it, but I wonder if this is good attitude.
If not, how can I make it done different way?

Also if validator class is empty, I mean it doesn't have any fields, only one method to validate that return true or false, is it ok to make dao layer and model layer for it?

Atm it is: Validator class, ValidatorDao class and ValidatorDaoInterface interface.

Is that correct approach?

model:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package xxx.model;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class Validator {

}
```

dao:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package xxx.dao;

import javax.servlet.http.Part;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public class ValidatorDao implements ValidatorDaoInterface {

    @Override
    public boolean validateFile(Part part, int numberOfFiles) {

     /*TODO*/

    }

}
```

interface:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package xxx.dao;

import javax.servlet.http.Part;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
public interface ValidatorDaoInterface {

    public boolean validateFile(Part part, int numberOfFiles);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes you can exclude classes that are not annotated with `@Entity` in your `Persitence.xml` file.

Just add this line to your `persitence-unit`

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

and you won't have to annotate your validator classes with `@Entity` because that's wrong.

Comment: so, for my understanding.. setting this value to false makes me no longer need to add every class to persistance.xml?

Comment: @arienn,yes but I don't recommend it . setting this to true and persistence.xml will only use the listed classes.